# Error al crear función que crea función y la aplica en python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Un saludo a todos, estoy siguiendo un [tutorial de Python 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0Lfm_rEQ2A).

El script trata de una función que crea otra función que a su vez es recibida por otra función que la ejecuta, en el vídeo se ejecuta sin ningún problema, tengo el mismo código que el vídeo linea por linea y no me funciona, me da error (si la ejecuta pero con error) y al tratar de hacer mi propia función no la ejecuta.

El código es el siguiente:

```
def crear_funcion(num_uno, num_dos):
    def validacion():
        print("Hace algo")
        return num_uno > 0 and num_dos > 0

    return validacion()

def aplicar_funcion(func):
    func()

nueva_funcion = crear_funcion(10, -5)
aplicar_funcion(nueva_funcion)
```

El error es el siguiente:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Hace algo
>     File "C:/Users/olask/PycharmProjects/aprender/funciones_anidadas.py", line 12, in 
>       aplicar_funcion(nueva_funcion)
>     File "C:/Users/olask/PycharmProjects/aprender/funciones_anidadas.py", line 9, in aplicar_funcion
>       func()
>   TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

La versión de Python del vídeo tutorial es *Python 3.5.1* la mía es *Python 3.5.2*, trato de entender este tema porque también me genera el mismo problema en decoradores.

Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reemplaza:

```
return validacion()
```

por

```
return validacion
```

Los paréntesis fuerzan la ejecución de la función en el momento de construirla que no es lo que quieres hacer.

Si eso está así en el vídeo es un bug. Quizás podrías informarlo.

¡Espero que disfrutes Python!

Comment: Efectivamente ese es el error, se te han escapado los paréntesis, si te fijas en el video del tutorial esos parentesis no existen.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora funciona bien.